Question on fractional Sobolev Hilbert Norms
Consider the fractional Sobolev Hilbert space $H^s(\mathbb{R})=W^{s,2}(\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the norm $\|f\|_{H^s} = \|(1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}\|_{L^2}$.  It seems clear to me that the following statement should be true, but I cannot think of the rigorous justification for this fact: $\|(1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}\|_{H^1} \leq \|f\|_{H^{s+1}}.$
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

It doesn't look true to me. To simplify take $s=0$. Then the left-hand side is $|\hat f |{H^1} \sim | (1+ |x|^2)^{1/2} f(x) |{L^2}$. Then you just need to find a function in $H^1$ which is not $L^2$ integrable when multiplied by $(1+ |x|^2)^{1/2}$ (probably $1/(1+|x|)$ works).

Thanks!  Do you think it would change anything if we assume higher regularity of f by assuming, for instance, that $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R})$ for $s>1$ or $s>2$ or some such?

I don't think so. I think a similar example would hold. Taking $f(x) = (1 + |x|^2)^{-1/2}$. This $f$ should be in any $H^{s+1}$ space but would not have a finite norm as given on the LHS in your question. Showing that might be a little messy, but it should be possible.

I think I came up with a proof for my question.  Recall Plancherel's Theorem for $H^m(\mathbb{R})$ functions, where $m$ is a non-negative integer,
$$\|\hat{f}\|_{H^m} = \|f\|_{H^m} = \|\check{f}\|_{H^m}.$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\|(1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}\|_{H^1} &= \|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big((1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}\big)\|_{H^1}\\
&= \|(1+|\cdot|^2)^{1/2}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big((1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}\big)\|_{L^2}\\
&= \|(1+|\cdot|^2)^{\frac{s+1}{2}}\hat{f}\|_{L^2} = \|f\|_{H^{s+1}}.
\end{align}
